# Server for multimedia and NAS porpuses: how to install Linux without consol?

Tags: linux, installation, nas, setup

I'm not very skilled Linux user and I don't really skilled in hardware but I'd like to try to setup home server for multimedia and data storage purposes.

I have the following equipment:

- Server
- Full HD TV connected via HDMI to the server
- WiFi Router Zyxel Keenetic (WAN connected to Internet, one of LANs to Server)
- Notebook with E-SATA interface connected to the router via WiFi (OS Windows XP)
- Probably I can add wireless keyboard and mouse to the set

As the Operation system I'd like to use one of Linux distributives.

I'd suppose the following:

1) Connect the server's HDD to the notebook via SATA and install Linux (and any graphic shell?) on it

2) Connect back HDD to server, start-up

3) Install and setup needed software (torrent client, NAS, media server, SSH...)

Questions:

- Is it OK to use Linux for such purposes (NAS, media content streaming, torrents and so on)? If 'yes' - which distributive will be better (personally I don't have any preferences)?
- Which way to interact with server's hardware is possible and better in my case: SATA to HDD, network or local?
- Will I be able to use TV as the monitor on step 2?

**UPDATE**

I just receive a suggestion from one of my friends to install FreeNAS on a flesh-drive for all these purposes. Looks attractive: off the shelf solution (less setup, almost all needed software included), easy installation using notebook and so on. But I have some doubts:

- Will I be able to install anything additional if I will need it? So can FreeNAS operate as an operation system in this case?
- I'm not really sure that FreeNAS is multimedia capable.

Can you comment on this?

Answer (score 1):

I've setup a NAS for storing data and multimedia files last year. So my answer is based on all my experience and research for my project.

> Is it OK to use Linux for such purposes (NAS, media content streaming, torrents and so on)? If 'yes' - which distributive will be better (personally I don't have any preferences)?

In general you could use any distribution available and install the packages you need. But the big advantage of e.g. FreeNAS is that most common packages which you would most properbly install are already implemented. Linux/ BSD is completly OK to use for such a purpose.

FreeNAS is based on BSD since i never used any kind of BSD system i personal wouldn't use it. 
I chose a Linux based system: OpenMediaVault. The reasons where that i had experience with debian and for my purpose the only advantage of FreeNAS was the ZFS file system which i didn't needed. Since you would also prefer a linux based distribution i would recommend Openmediavault.

Both systems have Transmission as torrent client in their plugin repo available.

Besides that both systems also offer SAMBA, so you cann access the stored files in your network via the SAMBA shares.

SSH is available on both systems. On Openmediavault you just have to enable it via the web-interface. (Guess the same applies for FreeNAS)

For the multimedia streaming you can chose between XBMC or Plex. I personaly fell in love with Plex, it was super easy to setup, has an app for any kind of smartphone, provides a nice web-interface and a distribution for the raspberry pi is available (Rasplex).

> Which way to interact with server's hardware is possible and better in my case: SATA to HDD, network or local?

I've some trouble understanding this question.
Espacially the SATA to HDD part. I would connect the HDD('s) via SATA with the server, create shares on them via SAMBA so you can access them from any computer. 
For the maintanance of the system remotely, i would use the ssh-shell and the provided web-interface.

> Will I be able to use TV as the monitor on step 2?

Of course. But i would already use the TV in step one as monitor. So the system installs the right drivers for the hardware on which it will be used later on.

Furthermore i wouldn't use the NAS to watch movies direct on the TV. I don't know what the specs of your server hardware are but running a window manager on a Server... There are a lot of discussions already going on everywhere. Even if this is nothing to server a website etc. just because of the 24/7 uptime i would try to keep the load as low as possible. You could of course install a windows manager and just start it if needed and otherwise turn him off.
I would use instead the laptop or an RasberryPi (Rasplex) as a client to watch movies on the TV.

> I just receive a suggestion from one of my friends to install FreeNAS on a flesh-drive for all these purposes.

I would not use a USB Flash-drive since both systems write a lot of logs all the time. Each USB stick just have a certain amount of write and read access in their lifetime.